# Gracefully handle variable number of input and output files

Tags: python, snakemake

You have a pipeline where some samples have one input file and produce one output file while other samples have two input files and produce two output files. The typical case for those in bioinformatics is NGS sequencing libraries where some samples are paired-end and other samples are single-end sequenced. If you need to trim reads and align them you have to account for the variable number of input/output files.

What is the most appropriate way to handle this? I feel using checkpoints is overkill since in my opinion checkpoints are a bit cryptic, but I may be wrong...

Here's how I would do it for the case where the number of input/output of files can be only 1 or 2: Have an `if-else` in the `run` directive based first on the number of input files. If the number of inputs is 1 touch the second files. For the following rules have again an `if-else` this time checking whether the second file has 0 bytes.

Here's an example (not tested but it should be about right):

```
import os

samples = {'S1': ['s1.R1.fastq'], 
           'S2': ['s2.R1.fastq', 's2.R2.fastq']}

rule all:
    input:
        expand('bam/{sample_id}.bam', sample_id= samples),

rule cutadapt:
    input:
        fastq= lambda wc: samples[wc.sample_id],
    output:
        r1= 'cutadapt/{sample_id}.R1.fastq',
        r2= touch('cutadapt/{sample_id}.R2.fastq'),
    run:
        if len(input.fastq) == 1:
            # {output.r1} created, {output.r2} touched
            shell('cutadapt ... -o {output.r1} {input.fastq}')
        else:
            shell('cutadapt ... -o {output.r1} -p {output.r2} {input.fastq}')

rule align:
    input:
        r1= 'cutadapt/{sample_id}.R1.fastq',
        r2= 'cutadapt/{sample_id}.R2.fastq',
    output:
        'bam/{sample_id}.bam',
    run:
        if os.path.getsize(input.r2) == 0:
        # or 
        # if len(samples[wildcards.sample_id]) == 1:
            shell('hisat2 ... {input.r1} > {output.bam}')
        else:
            shell('hisat2 ... -1 {input.r1} -2 {input.r2} > {output.bam}')
```

This works, but I find it awkward to artificially create the second file just to keep the workflow happy. Are there better solutions?

Comment: Perhaps you can hack something like this together? http://ivory.idyll.org/blog/2021-snakemake-checkpoints.html. I'm not entirely sure this would work

Answer (score 1):

There shall be two separate rules for single ended and pair ended case:

```py
rule single_end:
    input:
        fastq = 's{n}.R1.fastq'
    output:
        r1 = 'cutadapt/S{n}.R1.fastq'
    shell:
        'cutadapt ... -o {output.r1} {input.fastq}'

rule pair_ends:
    input:
        r1 = 's{n}.R1.fastq',
        r2 = 's{n}.R2.fastq'
    output:
        r1 = 'cutadapt/S{n}.R1.fastq',
        r2 = 'cutadapt/S{n}.R2.fastq'
    shell:
        'cutadapt ... -o {output.r1} -p {output.r2} {input}'
```

Now there is an ambiguity: whenever the `pair_ends` can be applied, the `single_end` may be applied too. This problem can be solved with can be `ruleorder`:

```py
ruleorder pair_ends > single_end
```

Comment: +1 but I'm not so sure about it. Having to duplicate rules for trimming and aligning perhaps is not better than my solution. Most important, fastq files for samples are typically stored in a dataframe or dictionary that you query with a function (e.g. my example). How do you handle it with your solution? This [attempt](https://gist.github.com/dariober/c0a6e88f2a61f771a48576718194963f) does not work since rule `pair_ends` is always used.

Comment: I would avoid using lambdas in your case. My approach works well only if the workflow is well defined by the patterns in filenames; providing the dependencies as a dict is an evil.

Comment: It looks like we are going to disagree here... I think depending on filename patterns is brittle and anyway you don't get to decide how files are named. You can rename them but it is equally brittle and confusing. In real code I don't use dictionaries I use tabular files, read as pandas dataframes, where I link sample IDs to their characteristics and fastq files.

Comment: Snakemake is designed to build pipelines on *patterns* where the patterns emerge from consistent file naming. Whenever you desire the "flexibility" to name files inconsistently, you should consider using bash or regular Python without Snakemake.

Comment: (It may very well be that we agree but comments are probably too short for this). Of course you are right that snakemake is based on file names. But at the start of the pipeline you have no control of what the raw input files are called so you need some flexibility there. I.e. you decide what the *output* of cutadapt is going to be and you rely on that from there on but you don't have control of what the initial *input* is named.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that checkpoints would be overkill here.

You can compose arbitrary inputs and command lines using input functions and parameter functions. The trick is optional r2 output from your `cutadapt` rule, which may or may not be present, which complicates the workflow's DAG. In this case it's probably appropriate to use Snakemake's [directories as output](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#directories-as-outputs) functionality:

```
CUTADAPT_R1 = 'cutadapt/{sample_id}/R1.fastq'
CUTADAPT_R2 = 'cutadapt/{sample_id}/R2.fastq'

def get_cutadapt_outargs(wldc, input):
    r1 = CUTADAPT_R1.format(**wldc)
    r2 = CUTADAPT_R2.format(**wldc)
    ret = f"-o '{r1}'"
    if len(input.fastq) > 1:
        ret += f" -p '{r2}'"
    return ret

def get_align_inargs(wldc):
    r1 = CUTADAPT_R1.format(**wldc)
    r2 = CUTADAPT_R2.format(**wldc)
    if len(samples[wldc.sample_id]) > 1:
        return "-1 '{}' -2 '{}'".format(r1, r2)
    else:
        return "'{}'".format(r1)

rule all:
    input:
        expand('bam/{sample_id}.bam', sample_id= samples),

rule cutadapt:
    input:
        fastq= lambda wc: samples[wc.sample_id],
    output:
        fq = directory('cutadapt/{sample_id}'),
    params:
        out_args = get_cutadapt_outargs,
    shell:
        """
        cutadapt ... {params.out_args} {input.fastq}
        """

rule align:
    input:
        fq = rules.cutadapt.output.fq,
    output:
        bam = 'bam/{sample_id}.bam',
    params:
        input_args = get_align_inargs,
    shell:
        """
        hisat2 ... {params.input_args} > {output.bam}
        """
```